# Is there a developers image of 16.04 LTS?

Tags: virtualbox, iso

Installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Oracle's VM VirtualBox (hosted on a modern Windows 10 64-bit machine) went unexpectedly well and without issue. Very nice indeed!

The primary reason for Ubuntu's installation is to run a particular UNIX program, one which I'm presently attempting to compile. However, it seems that there are numerous libraries missing from the offered image (*ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso*), ones which might chiefly be used by developers, so it makes sense that they weren't included. This apparent sufficiency of only runtime files begs a question:

**Is there such a thing as a developers image of 16.04 LTS?**

I'm not a developer(!), just a new user of Ubuntu trying to compile XTide which needs libraries; such as,

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev xorg-dev
```

Comment: You could just install the necessary libraries you need. I don't think there is a separate ubuntu version  for developers or I think the general version itself is for developers. Ubuntu(the general 16.04.1 iso) comes with lots of compilers and developement tools inbuilt.

Comment: If you do not need the latest version of Xtides, you can get it already compiled from the software repositories.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you will also need:

```
libxaw3dxft8
libxaw3dxft8-dev
libxmu-dev
libxmu-headers
libxt-dev
libxpm-dev
xaw3dg
xaw3dg-dev
xutils-dev
libtcd-dev
libtcd0
```

With these additions, I was able to get *configure* completed for `xtide-2.15.1`.

Answer (score 10):

No, there is no such thing. We have only 1 system to cover all (even the server version nowadays is the same core as a desktop version; all that one lacks is a desktop).

But all you need to do is install the libraries you need and that could be done with 1 `apt install` command if you got a list of them (as you already shown in your question).

Answer (score 3):

If you are compiling a custom build of a package provided by the Ubuntu then you should be able to get a source package and the dependencies needed to build it with:

```
sudo apt-get source <package>
sudo apt-get build-dep <package>
```

Comment: I think you should put `sudo` in front of `apt-get build-dep` to make it obvious which of the two commands is supposed to be run as root and which is not.